# DSE search get distinct count of a column

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

DSE search get distinct count of a column.

Am unable to perform a distinct of count of a query in DSE search :

```
SELECT * FROM mykeyspace.mysolr WHERE solr_query='quotes:succ*';
```

In the above query i need to get distinct values of the quotes column.

Like :

```
select count(distinct(quotes)) from mykeyspace.mysolr WHERE 
solr_query='quotes:succ*';
```

But it is failing.

Any suggestions appreciated.

### ***Update:***

Say we have a Column Airport .
Id | Airport | FlightNum
**1 | AL | 1**
2 | AG | 2
3 | AK | 3
**4 | AL | 3**
5 | AM | 2

So in the above , i need to find the number of distinct airports that start with A*

SELECT * FROM mykeyspace.Flights WHERE solr_query='Airport:A*';

I need the answer as :

A* | 4

Answer is 4 because AL is repeated twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly with CQL as it doesn't support `count(distinct(...))` (see [syntax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html)), but you can do the trick with Solr faceting & small data processing on application side:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM solr WHERE 
    solr_query='{"q":"quotes:succ*","facet":{"field":"quotes"}}';

 facet_fields
--------------------------------------------
 {"quotes":{"succ3":2,"succ1":1,"succ2":1}}

(1 rows)
```

You can get result, and parse resulting from JSON string, and then extract all necessary data.  More documentation on solr_query for facets is [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/siQuerySyntax.html#queriesJSON__solrFacetquery).

Comment: Hey @Alex Ott, am getting the above answer.  Is there anyway i can get a distinct and sum.
Say, having a sum of the total distinct values.
succ3 is1,succ1 is 1,succ2 is 1.
Answer:
succ* : 3

Comment: you need summe of what?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: yes, if you use both field & query facets, like this: `SELECT * FROM q WHERE solr_query='{"q":"quotes:succ*","facet":{"field":"quotes", "query":"quotes:succ*"}}';`

Comment: Will i be getting a count as above. I have updated the question.

Comment: Not sure, you can try to use queries that I've shown

Comment: Am almost there.



SELECT origin FROM flight_exercise.flight_by_origin_by_day WHERE solr_query='{"q":"origin:A*","facet":{"field":"origin", "query":"origin:A*"}}'



..............................................Gives me below result ;..................
 
{"origin:A*":42625}


..........................But what i need is the count of the distinct values of Airports that begin with A. This gives only a total. Am unable to do distinct on this.

Comment: If am able to do something like select DISTINCT origin it would be great.

Comment: just get the JSON string from `facet_fields`, deserialize it into `map = Map<String, Object>`, do `Map<String,Object> m = map.get("quotes");` and call `m.size()` on it - this will gives you a number of distinct entries. If you need the entries themself, call `m.keys()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176882/discussion-between-ashwinsakthi-and-alex-ott).